# Split by Attributes tool exporting to DBF files only?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, file-formats, split-by-attribute

I am using the "Split by Attributes" tool in ArcGIS 10.6 to go through a shapefile, and split it up into new files by an attribute value. The tool runs perfectly, however I notice it only exports to DBF files. Shapefiles or CSVs would be preferable, but I don't see any option to specify the file type.

Can this be changed and, if not, is there a way to split up a shapefile by attribute value, and export it to .shp or .csv files?

Comment: According to the docs http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm Split by Attributes is a table tool and outputs *tables*, hence the dbf files with no shp. Are you executing this from the toolbox or from a python script?

Comment: From the toolbox... I've been able to split by attributes to shapefiles in the past but have been unable to replicate it. Maybe I was using a different tool that I can't recall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, I am unsure whether this tool can take an input of a shapefile, and create shapefiles as output on its own.

If it cannot, then you could use ModelBuilder or ArcPy to convert your shapefile to a file geodatabase feature class, and then when [Split By Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) splits it into feature classes in your target workspace (I would use a file geodatabase here), iterate through those feature classes, and convert them to shapefiles.